# RecyclerView - Delete row always deletes the last one

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my MainActivity I've got a RecyclerView for which I implemented a swipe to delete feature:

```
private val swipeHelper = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition //get position which is swipe

        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {  //if swipe left
            deleteSwipe(position)
        } else {
            editSwipe(position)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

and this is how the deleteSwipe() function looks like:

```
private fun deleteSwipe(position: Int) {
        try {
            adapter.removeItem(position)
            ...
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {}
    }
```

And here is my `removeItem(pos:Int)` function in the adapter:

```
fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    activeFiltered!!.removeAt(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

notice that I on purpose used `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `notifyItemRemoved()` because I don't want the animation.

The problem is that no matter which item in the list I swipe on, the one that is deleted is always the last one. I debugged the position variable and it's the one I expect, so I don't really know where the mistake is.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work correctly when you notifyItemRemoved passing in the position variable?

Comment: yes it works correctly @WadeWilson

Comment: Try using notifyItemRemoved() again but when creating your list remove the item animator (call setItemAnimator(null) on the RecyclerView) and see if it removes the correct item.

Comment: @WadeWilson It worked, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I don't know why the other solution isn't working. Could be a RecyclerView bug, but that is a suitable workaround since you don't want animations anyway. I'm going to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure of why `notifyDataSetChanged()` is removing the incorrect object but if you don't want animations, you can disable animations on the Recyclerview using the method [`setItemAnimator(ItemAnimator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)) and passing in `null`. Instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify RecyclerView of change (also this is inefficient), you should call the method [`notifyItemRemoved(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) and pass in the position you want to remove. This will disable the animations, and only notify the RecyclerView of precisely which item was removed (very efficient).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will avoid notifyDataSetChanged whenever I can, since it is lately causing more harm than good.